# Sencha touch custom list into viewport

Tags: list, extjs, sencha-touch, viewport

I am having some problems adding my custom list view into the viewport.
If i use the example from the documentation like the lines below it works fine

```
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Ext.List', {
store: {
    fields: ['name'],
    data: [
        {name: 'Cowper'},
        {name: 'Everett'},
        {name: 'University'},
        {name: 'Forest'}
    ]
},

itemTpl: '{name}'
}));
```

If i define my own list and then try to add it it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
Ext.define('MyList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    store: 
    { fields: ['name'],
      data: [{name: 'Cowper'},
            {name: 'Everett'},
            {name: 'University'},
            {name: 'Forest'}],
    },
    itemTpl: '{name}'});
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyList'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define view, you should put view configuration inside config.

Try this

```
Ext.define('MyList',{
        extend: 'Ext.List',
        config: {
            store: { 
                fields: ['name'],
                data: [{name: 'Cowper'},
                {name: 'Everett'},
                {name: 'University'},
                {name: 'Forest'}],
            },
            itemTpl: '{name}'
       }
});

Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyList'));
```